# Rails filtering with acts_as_taggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I am working the acts-as-taggable-on gem and have a question about how to filter down search results based on tags users select. Here's an abridged look at my controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @photos = Photo.where(["created_at > ? AND is_approved = ?", 1.months.ago, true])
    @tags = ["Animals", "Architecture", "Cars", "Flowers", "Food/Drink", "General", "Landscape", "Mountains", "Nature"]
  end

  def search_by_tag(tag)
    @photos = Photo.where('tagged_with LIKE ?', tag)
  end
end
```

Photos/index

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag, {:search_by_tag => tag}, :class => "tag" %>
<% end %>
```

This lists out all of the tags from the hash `@tags` defined in `index`, but clicking them doesn't actually filter anything down. Here's a look at what clicking one of those links produces in the log:

```
Started GET "/photos?search_by_tag=Animals" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Oct 09 17:11:09 -0400 2011
Processing by PhotosController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"search_by_tag"=>"Animals"}
SQL (0.5ms)   SELECT name  FROM sqlite_master  WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
```

The result I want is for the page to display only Photos that are `tagged_with` whichever tag was clicked on. I can't quite figure out how to accomplish this.

(Side-question: I can't seem to find a way to list out all of the tags from the `tags` table that acts-as-taggable-on generated. Doing something like `Photo.tagged_with` or `Photo.tags` doesn't work. I am able to see the "tags" table the gem created, and the entries inside of it; I'm just not really clear how to handle that using this gem)

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've updated my code and am a bit closer.

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def search_by_tag
    @photos = Photo.tagged_with(params[:tag_name])
  end
```

photos/index

```
<% Photo.tag_counts_on(:tags).map(&:name).each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag, {:action => 'search_by_tag', :tag_name => tag}, :class => "tag" %>
<% end %>
```

I believe this is closer, but still working through this...

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of errors in your code:

1. Your `link_to` call is actually calling the `index` action.
2. Your `search_by_tag` method is expecting an argument, where it should be using the `params` hash to access the parameters passed to it in the web request.
3. `tagged_with` is a class method added by acts_as_taggable_on, not a field in your table - therefore you can't use it in the `where` method like you have done.

Finally, to get all the tag names: `Photo.tag_counts_on(:tags_or_whatever_you_tagged_on).map(&:name)`

Take a look at [the acts_as_taggable_on documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and you'll see examples of how to use `tag_counts_on` and `tagged_with`.

As for the Rails things: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ http://railsforzombies.org/ and/or http://railscasts.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help Jason. Could you review the update above? I feel like I'm closer, but still not there.

Comment: What are you getting now?  An error about no route matching?  You need the route in there, take a look at [the routes doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  But better, look at [the Getting Started docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: I'm still working on this, but to answer your question, the error it's giving me is "Couldn't find Photo with ID=search_by_tag".